# Creating a new dataframes based on two conditions from two other dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I'm fairly new to coding languages and have been asked to create a new dataframe based on two existing dataframes. Dataframe 1 is the original and dataframe 2 is a subset of the original. The new data frame needs to be a copy of the original with certain scores removed if they meet certain conditions from
df2, ie identify the task type in df2 and remove the corresponding value from df1, if the sample ID matches.

E.g.Dataframe1:

```
sample_id  Low    Mid  High

13420       NA    2.4  3.7
43905       7.5   NA   NA
52078       5.6   3.2  5.6
43292       10    NA   1.9
79327       5.7   3.2  NA
```

Dataframe2:

```
Sample    Task type

13420       High
52078       Low
52078       Mid
43292       High
79327       Low


New dataframe:

13420       NA    2.4  NA
43905       7.5   NA   NA
52078       NA    NA   5.6
43292       10    NA   NA
79327       NA    3.2  NA
```

Can anyone help, please? I've tried a few conditional statements, but have had no luck.

Comment: You have both [tag:r] and [tag:python] tags. Please clarify what language you want your answer in.

Comment: I would be more comfortable with r

Comment: Can you try explain the filtering conditions? Since you have `13420=High` in df2, but you keep the "mid" value in the `New dataframe` it is not clear how you would filter

Comment: df2 was used as a list to select training material, we want to select a new list from df1, but need to filter out the values that have already been use in df2

Answer (score 1):

**sample data**

```
df1 <- data.table::fread("sample_id   Low   Mid  High
13420       NA    2.4  3.7
43905       7.5   NA   NA
52078       5.6   3.2  5.6
43292       10    NA   1.9
79327       5.7   3.2  NA")

df2 <- data.table::fread("Sample      Tasktype
13420       High
52078       Low
52078       Mid
43292       High
79327       Low")
```

**code**

```
library( data.table )    
#or make data.frames a data.table
data.table::setDT(df1);data.table::setDT(df2)

#melt df1 to long format
df1.melt <- melt( df1, id.vars = "sample_id" )
#update join the molten dataset with df2, updating the value with NA
df1.melt[ df2, value := NA, on = .(sample_id = Sample, variable = Tasktype) ]
#and cast df1 wit the new values back to wide format
dcast( df1.melt, sample_id ~ variable, value.var = "value" )
```

**output**

```
#    sample_id  Low Mid High
# 1:     13420   NA 2.4   NA
# 2:     43292 10.0  NA   NA
# 3:     43905  7.5  NA   NA
# 4:     52078   NA  NA  5.6
# 5:     79327   NA 3.2   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(-sample_id) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("sample_id" = "Sample",
                        "name" = "Task.type"),
            keep = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(!is.na(Task.type) & Task.type == name,
                        NA_real_, value)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-c(Sample,Task.type)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("sample_id"))
## A tibble: 5 x 4
#  sample_id   Low   Mid  High
#      <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     13420  NA     2.4  NA  
#2     43905   7.5  NA    NA  
#3     52078  NA    NA     5.6
#4     43292  10    NA    NA  
#5     79327  NA     3.2  NA
```

**Sample Data**

```
df1<-structure(list(sample_id = c(13420L, 43905L, 52078L, 43292L, 
79327L), Low = c(NA, 7.5, 5.6, 10, 5.7), Mid = c(2.4, NA, 3.2, 
NA, 3.2), High = c(3.7, NA, 5.6, 1.9, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
df2 <- structure(list(Sample = c(13420L, 52078L, 52078L, 43292L, 79327L
), Task.type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("High", 
"Low", "Mid"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```